# package org.apache.commons.collections.map does not exist import org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

When I used library collections for multivalue Maps on the esclipse, all things are Ok for build application.
However, when I configured xml file to run by command lines,
the error happened when running application.
Although, I copied all library that I used when run on eclipse into lib folder.
the message error: "package org.apache.commons.collections.map does not exist import org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiValueMap"
Please tell me the way to config it.
Thanks

Comment: Have you added commomc-collection JAR file to the classloader ?

Comment: Have you configured the classpath for the command line?

Comment: Yes, we added library, other libraries are received by the system except commoms.collections

Answer (score 1):

Try with `-classpath common-collections.jar` in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Package name for collection is changed from `collections` to `collections4` with latest jar file.

*How I got into this issue and solved:*

I upgraded jar version to [commons-collections4-4.4.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.4), and got into this error.

I changed import statement in my java file, which linked to new jar as follows

Error: `import org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap;`

New (update): `import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.HashedMap;`

and error resolve. Hope it may help.